# Optimizing Postgres query with timestamp filter

Tags: postgresql, query-performance, postgresql-9.5

I have a query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (analytics_staging_v2s.event_type, sent_email_v2s.recipient, sent_email_v2s.sent) sent_email_v2s.id, sent_email_v2s.user_id, analytics_staging_v2s.event_type, sent_email_v2s.campaign_id, sent_email_v2s.recipient, sent_email_v2s.sent, sent_email_v2s.stage, sent_email_v2s.sequence_id, people.role, people.company, people.first_name, people.last_name, sequences.name as sequence_name 
FROM "sent_email_v2s" 
  LEFT JOIN analytics_staging_v2s ON sent_email_v2s.id = analytics_staging_v2s.sent_email_v2_id 
  JOIN people ON sent_email_v2s.person_id = people.id 
  JOIN sequences on sent_email_v2s.sequence_id = sequences.id 
  JOIN users ON sent_email_v2s.user_id = users.id 
WHERE "sent_email_v2s"."status" = 1 
  AND "people"."person_type" = 0 
  AND (sent_email_v2s.sequence_id = 1888) AND (sent_email_v2s.sent >= '2016-03-18') 
  AND "users"."team_id" = 1
```

When I run EXPLAIN ANALYZE on it, I get:

[image]

Then, if I change that to the following (Just removing the (sent_email_v2s.sent >= '2016-03-18')) as follows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (analytics_staging_v2s.event_type, sent_email_v2s.recipient, sent_email_v2s.sent) sent_email_v2s.id, sent_email_v2s.user_id, analytics_staging_v2s.event_type, sent_email_v2s.campaign_id, sent_email_v2s.recipient, sent_email_v2s.sent, sent_email_v2s.stage, sent_email_v2s.sequence_id, people.role, people.company, people.first_name, people.last_name, sequences.name as sequence_name 
FROM "sent_email_v2s" 
  LEFT JOIN analytics_staging_v2s ON sent_email_v2s.id = analytics_staging_v2s.sent_email_v2_id 
  JOIN people ON sent_email_v2s.person_id = people.id 
  JOIN sequences on sent_email_v2s.sequence_id = sequences.id 
  JOIN users ON sent_email_v2s.user_id = users.id 
WHERE "sent_email_v2s"."status" = 1 
  AND "people"."person_type" = 0 
  AND (sent_email_v2s.sequence_id = 1888) AND "users"."team_id" = 1
```

when I run EXPLAIN ANALYZE on this query, the results are:

[image]

EDIT:

The results above from today are about as I expected. When I ran this last night, however, the difference created by including the timestamp filter was about 100x slower (0.5s -> 59s). The EXPLAIN ANALYZE from last night showed all of the time increase to be attributed to the first unique/sort operation in the query plan above.

Could there be some kind of caching issue here? I am worried now that there might be something else going on (transiently) that might make this query take 100x longer since it happened at least once.

Any thoughts are appreciated!

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us the **complete** execution plans - make sure you preserve the format and indention. You can also upload them to http://explain.depesz.com

Comment: Edited to include the full query plans + some more info

Comment: You have to add the information as text, not as image, so one can use copy & paste with it. If the `EXPLAIN` output doesn't exhibit the problem, it is hard to analyze. Maybe use `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` so that you can see how many database pages are used in each step.